# reCaptcha on Vagrant (not localhost)

Tags: localhost, vagrant, recaptcha

I've searched a lot, but all questions I found are about *localhost*. I know it works on localhost or 127.0.0.1, but I'm trying to test reCaptcha on my machine with vagrant.

My local page IP is 192.168.10.10 and in *hosts* file (Win8) I have `192.168.10.10  local.page.dev`. Tried in reCaptcha settings adding page.dev domain, but no luck - reCapctha just isn't rendered.

Any chance to test it on local machine, but not localhost?

Answer (score 1):

I found changing your `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` to your registered domain in reCaptcha work fine.

The most easy (and hackish) way is just to insert `<?php $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = 'yourdomain.com' ?>` inside your form, just before your captcha script.

But I think you can also change it in your PHP configuration file too...
(Sorry, still learning about web development and PHP)

Answer (score 1):

this may help someone if struggling. We can just add the domain you map on your vagrant environment on google. It may take several minutes.
here: https://github.com/lepture/flask-wtf/issues/180

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by, "the domain you map on your vagrant environment". Would that just be localhost? Do I add localhost + the port number?

Answer (score 0):

The question is old but the problem is still current. The solution that worked for me:

1. Set up port forwarding in Vagrantfile for apache and reload the virtual machine. Eg.:
   config.vm.network 'forwarded_port', guest: 80, host: 80
2. Add the domain at which you will access your page in the reCaptcha admin console. It may be "localhost" or whatever you have defined in the local hosts file.

Now, you should be able to access your page with reCaptcha on http://localhost/path/to/page

Comment: the solution that worked for me was: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47439938/how-do-i-use-recaptcha-in-a-vagrant-development-environment