# How do I use reCaptcha in a vagrant development environment?

Tags: vagrant, recaptcha

I am developing using vagrant. I'd like to use reCapcha how ever I get an error when when I'm developing on local machine which is at a subdomain on the vagrant configured private network 192.168.100.100:

```
ERROR for site owner:
Invalid domain for site key
```

The recaptcha works on the production site fine. How can I setup my development environment to work with recaptcha?

In the vagrant bootstrap are the following:

```
<Directory "/var/www/">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/app
    ServerName app.dev
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/phpmyadmin
    ServerName phpmyadmin.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

I've tried adding locahost and 192.168.100.100 to my recaptcha key settings but this hasn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

Add your domain to `/etc/hosts` with your local vargrant IP. Then visit your domain in a browser and it should be working.

Comment: I have already added `192.168.100.100 app.dev` to /etc/hosts. I access my site by going to app.dev

Comment: So change `app.dev` to your production domain.

Comment: I've just done that but accessing my site on that address now takes me to the `Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page`

Comment: Can you show config of apache. You need to expose your site on port 80 at for your domain.

Comment: ok ... how do I do that? What do you want to see from the conf file?

Comment: Just change `ServerName` to your domain